# Django: ModelManager

Tags: python, django

I created a model manager that should delete the entry. I always receive the error `delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Can anyone explain to me why I get this message?

view.py

```
ReservedItem.objects.delete(order_reference)
```

models.py

```
class ReservedItemManager(models.Manager):
    def delete(order_reference):

    super().get_queryset().filter(order_reference=order_reference).delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `self` in your method definition.

Because of this, Python treated your `order_reference` parameter as the `self` parameter (because its name doesn't make any difference and the name `self` is only a convention), so Python thought your method didn't take any additional parameters and raised an exception when you tried to call it with parameters.

Your class definition should be like this:

```
class ReservedItemManager(models.Manager):
    def delete(self, order_reference):  # <-- note `self` here
        super().get_queryset().filter(order_reference=order_reference).delete()
```